# Cycles rendering all grey or transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was rendering a fairly complex scene and cycles was rendering all grey. I tried setting up render layers and now it renders one layer, but it is all transparent.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Including screenshots and a .blend file will help people to answer your question. Right now, there could be any of a million answers that would work for you. A .blend  file can be uploaded to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. There are a multiple reasons why that might be happening. Add images of your current scene, render settings, render layers and compositor nodes... It might also be an issue with the particular GPU you might be using... so please add more info as part of your question....